# PHP recursive function to generate tree structured menu

Tags: php

I have created a MySQL database table where I want to show the menu structure based on their parent. The menu table contains the following data:

```
id | menuname          | parentid
---+-------------------+---------
 1 | dashboard         |        0
 2 | Content           |        0
 3 | Home Page Content |        2
 4 | Banners           |        2
 5 | Settings          |        0
 6 | Block Content     |        3
 7 | Site Content      |        3
```

So that the menu structure will look like:

- dashboard
- Content

  - Home Page Content

    - Block Content
    - Site Content
- Banners
- Settings

I have gone though the post over here [Recursive menu tree from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31532859/recursive-menu-tree-from-array)
however, unable to understand the basics. However, the idea I understood that I need to write a recursive function to sort out this. Can someone give me some ideas how to generate the above?

Comment: For starters you should use `select * from my_table order by parentid ASC, id ASC` and the rest will need to be PHP logic. Also, why isn't `Banners` a child of `Content` in your example? If you are interested in hierarchical table structures and queries in MySQL then you can check out https://stackoverflow.com/q/20215744/2191572

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you are selected from database with sql query

```
SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY parentid ASC, id ASC
```

and you have this array in PHP

```
$arr = [

    [
        "id"=>1,
        "username"=>"dashboard",
        "parentid"=>0
    ],
    [
        "id"=>2,
        "username"=>"dashboard",
        "parentid"=>0
    ],
    [
        "id"=>5,
        "username"=>"dashboard",
        "parentid"=>0
    ],
    [
        "id"=>3,
        "username"=>"dashboard",
        "parentid"=>2
    ],
    [
        "id"=>4,
        "username"=>"dashboard",
        "parentid"=>2
    ],
    [
        "id"=>6,
        "username"=>"dashboard",
        "parentid"=>3
    ],
    [
        "id"=>7,
        "username"=>"dashboard",
        "parentid"=>3
    ],

];

$categories = [];
    foreach ($arr as $item){
        if($item["parentid"]==0){
            $categories[$item["id"]] = $item;
        }else{
            $categories[$item["parentid"]]["subs"][] = $item;
        }
    }
```